# Trouble thinking of name for coding blog

Tags: wordpress

I am starting an online web development blog aimed for teenagers and i need ideas for a name. I have thought of Code Overload, could anyone suggest anything else?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's polling for a name and has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: danronmoon, i am not polling, i am merely asking for suggestions for a good name for computer programming blog